# xmlin function of Perl in php

Tags: php, perl

```
my $config = XMLin($response_body, KeyAttr => { server => 'name' }, ForceArray => [ 'server', 'address' ]);
```

i don't understand what is `xmlin` , `keyattr` and `force array` 
please tell me if there is some function in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `XMLIn` is exported from the [XML::Simple CPAN module](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple). It lets you convert an XML document/string to a Perl data structure. Both `KeyAttr` and `ForceArray` are configuration settings for the parser.

[Docs on `ForceArray`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#ForceArray-names-in---important):

> This alternative (and preferred) form of the 'ForceArray' option allows you to specify a list of element names which should always be forced into an array representation, rather than the 'all or nothing' approach above. [...]

[Docs on `KeyAttr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#KeyAttr-list-in-out---important1):

> This alternative (and preferred) method of specifiying the key attributes allows more fine grained control over which elements are folded and on which attributes. For example the option 'KeyAttr => { package => 'id' } will cause any package elements to be folded on the 'id' attribute. No other elements which have an 'id' attribute will be folded at all. [...]

A quick google gave me [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) as a PHP equivalent. I also found a [blogpost that nicely describes how to use it](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-parse-xml-with-php5).

You can use it in PHP like this:

```
<?
// ... $response_body should be there
$config = new SimpleXMLElement($response_body);

var_dump($config);
?>
```

It makes sense to look at the XML document because the resulting data structure will probably be different in PHP than it was in Perl (not only because of hashes vs. arrays with named keys).

Answer (score 1):

What that is an import mechanism used by the [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) library to parse XML. The `XML::Simple` man page warns:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

This isn't a good approach to XML parsing though, so I wouldn't worry about it too much - look instead at `$response_body` - which will be some XML data - and how you process it to extract what you want.

Without knowing what your source XML looks like though, it's impossible to say what `XMLin` will be returning.

Comment: forget the $response_body this is xml data

Comment: Yes. Parsing XML isn't hard, but going through `XML::Simple` makes it harder. I would suggest you roll back a bit, and just parse the XML directly.

Comment: OP is not asking about how to parse, he wants to know what XML::Simple does and if there is a php equivalent.